# How to use ImageResizer to resize/corp image?

Tags: imageresizer

I need resize/corp image to 96x96 and the file size under 5k. How to set ImageResizer to achieve these goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ImageResizer.Net you can specify with (?w=96) and height=(&h=96) for the width and decide on the scaling model e.g. (&mode=max)

However you cannot specify max size, you can experiment with both the file format (format=gif|png|jpg) or/and quality  (q=50 (0..100)) to find the best setting for a range of images

More info available at http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics

Thanks

Shane

Comment: The resized image size is a hard limit, if ImageResizer can't do, I'll have to look for something else. Thanks for your quick answer

Comment: Remember that the only way to know the compressed size of an image is to actually compress it. To meet a file size limit you would have to repeatedly compress an image, perhaps 5-20 times. As encoding is often the slowest part of image processing, you'll get horrendous performance no matter what tools you use.